# How to fix this Error: HTTP ERROR 500 and chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file for WordPress

Tags: apache-httpd, yum, selinux, aws, wordpress

I am trying to correct this piece of code but I have an error and the code doesn't executed. I would like to use a Public IP to run WordPress as well.

The problem is that I can't run sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/ -R because I am receiving an error "chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled"

The second problem is that If I am using Pulic IP for example http://x.x.x.x/wordpress for my Instance of WordPress in browser I am receiving HTTP ERROR 500. I have wordpress files in directroy /var/www/html and my Apache is running.

Errors:

```
aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): Failed to restart service\x0d.service: Unit not found.
aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): --2020-08-19 13:04:52--  https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz%0D
aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): Resolving wordpress.org (wordpress.org)... 198.143.164.252
aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): Connecting to wordpress.org (wordpress.org)|198.143.164.252|:443... connected.
aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): 2020-08-19 13:04:52 ERROR 400: Bad Request.

aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): tar: latest.tar.gz\r: Cannot open: No such file or directory
aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): mv: cannot stat ‘wordpress/*’: No such file or directory
aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): chown: cannot access ‘/var/www/html/\r’: No such file or directory
aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): chcon: invalid option -- '
aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): '
aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): Try 'chcon --help' for more information.
aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): sed: can't read /etc/selinux/config
aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): : No such file or directory
aws_instance.wp (remote-exec): setenforce: SELinux is disabled
aws_instance.wp: Creation complete after 58s [id=i-0068d9c9935666018]
```

This below code I am using:

```
#!/bin/bash#Update yum
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum -y install httpd
sudo systemctl enable httpd service
sudo systemctl start httpd service
sudo yum install wget -y
sudo yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
sudo yum-config-manager --disable remi-php54
sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
sudo yum install -y php php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql php-ldap php-zip php-fileinfo
sudo systemctl restart httpd service
sudo wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvf latest.tar.gz
sudo rm -rf latest.tar.gz
sudo rm -rf /var/www/html/*
sudo mv wordpress/* /var/www/html/
sudo rm -rf wordpress
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/ -R
sudo sed -i s/^SELINUX=.*$/SELINUX=permissive/ /etc/selinux/config
sudo setenforce 0
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Comment: It looks like there are some carriage returns in the file (\r or 0x0d).   The shell (bash) can't read files with DOS/Windows line endings properly, make sure the file has been saved properly with unix line endings.

Comment: For example this doesn't work too:  sudo systemctl restart httpd.service

Comment: How to check this?

Comment: Look for line ending in whichever text editor you're using, setting it to unix line endings and saving the file should fix the problem.  // If you have the `hd` or `hexdump` command installed, you can use it to see the file's content in binary, if you see 0d 0a you know it's Windows line endings.

Comment: I am using Notepad++ I don't see any specific characters on end of the lines.

Comment: On the bottom right of the window, it's probably saying "Windows (CR LF)". Right click on that and choose "Unix (LF)"